# Chumash with Rashi and Siftei Chachamim

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, rashi, commentaries, pentateuch-chumash

Does anyone know of a Chumash (not Mikraot Gedolot) with `Rashi` and `Siftei Chachamim`

Most Chumashim come with `Ikar Siftei Chachamim`, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Note that four commentaries on _Rashi_ on _Chumash_ are published together, usually titled after the author of one of those four: _Mizrachi_. One of them is _Sifse Chachamim_. But this is not an answer to your question, as the volume doesn't include _Chumash_ or _Rashi_.

Comment: this one says Siftei Chachamim rather than Ikkar Siftei Chachamim: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&pgnum=474 Can compare with this text http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19175&st=&pgnum=43 to see if it is complete

Comment: @joshwaxman Most Sifsei Chachamims that come in Mikra'os Gedolos chumashim are incomplete. A notable exception is [HaMo`or](http://www.judaism.com/display.asp?nt=aRHn&usn=199). (By the way, I think he's asking for a chumash with only those two commentaries.)

Comment: What is the difference between Siftei Chachamim and Ikar Siftei Chachamim?

Comment: I think the Dirshu Humash has all three including Ramban and it's not Mikraot Gedolot.

Comment: @HachamGabriel I have no problem with Mikraot Gedolot (Chas VShalom), my intention was to find a sefer which on one hand included Siftei Chachamim and on the other was light-weight - where a thin sefer will cover a whole book of Chumash (like the many publications which include Chumash,Onkelos and Rashi with Ikar Siftei Chachamim)

Comment: @Danield oh well then that's not what you want because the Chumash is very large.